# Javascript - variable scope

Tags: javascript

I am not seeing the issue here. I am new at JavaScript. I have researched variable scope and this looks correct to me. The issue is the variable, useAge, in the legalAge function is undefined. I have it declared before the function and passing it as a parameter to the function.

```
"use strict";

function person(){
    alert("person function 1");
    var personName = prompt("Enter a name:", "enter name here");
    var personAge = parseInt(prompt("Enter " +  personName + "'s current age:", "enter age here"));
    var votingStatus = legalAge();
    var statusMessage =  (votingStatus == true) ? "old enough" : "not old enough";
    document.writeln("<b>" + personName + " is " + personAge + " years old " + statusMessage + "</b><br />");
    return personAge;   
}


var useAge = person();
alert("useAge: " + useAge);
alert("outside function");

function legalAge(useAge) {
  alert("legalVoting function 2");
  var canVote = (useAge >= 18) ? true : false;  
  alert("Can Vote: " + canVote);
  alert("age: " + useAge);
  return canVote;       
}

person();
```

Comment: You could reduce the canVote line to `var canVote = useAge >= 18;`

Comment: Also, the last line is not really needed is it?

Comment: *"and passing it as a parameter to the function."* No your a not.

Comment: You are correct, the last line is not needed.

Comment: Felix, I was referring to useAge variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't passed `personAge` into the `legalAge()` function. You need:

```
var votingStatus = legalAge(personAge);
```

Otherwise `useAge` in `legalAge()` is undefined and you'll get errors using it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo mate :)

Comment: Thank you. I passed "personage" into the legalAge() function. I was looking at it like it was being passed with the useAge variable that is = person().

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to note here:

```
var useAge = person()
```

The above line will assign the return value from person() to useAge sure enough...

```
function legalAge(useAge) {
    ....
}
```

The above function has a parameter called useAge which is local to the function, and must be passed as an argument when calling the function.  I.E. legalAge(10).  This would be fine and dandy, except...

```
function person() {
    ....
    var votingStatus = legalAge();
    ....
}
```

the person() function is defined to call legalAge() with no parameters.  In doing so, legalAge executes and does not have a value for its parameter.

Also, the useAge parameter is different from the global useAge variable.

Hope this helps!